# Azure DevOps: When does Build.Repository.LocalPath change?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I had a pipeline that was running for several month, the local path (`Build.Repository.LocalPath`) was `/agent/_work/2/s/DP/tests/integration`.
Suddenly, the local path is `/agent/_work/4/s/DP/tests/integration`: When is the path changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare these path you will notice that difference is on `2` and `4`. But it doesn't matter. You just got a new agent and got new number for your job as there were already 1, 2 and 3.

[image]

This is assigned automatically based on the number of jobs were already running on specific agent.

Comment: Could you consider upvote my reply if it was helpful?

Comment: sure, just did it!